# Не передаются данные в input атрибут max с использованием jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

Нужно после того как в

`select name="item" id="item"`

будет выбрано определенную строку атрибуту

`max в input type="number" name="count"  max="" id = "count"`

присваивалось максимальное значение, которое было выбрано из **БД**.
Вот код, но почему-то ничего не работает `max в input number` не ограничивается, что не правильно?

```
<label for="item">Goods</label>
<select name="item" id="item">
  <option value="">Select goods</option>
</select>
<br><br>
<label for="count">Count</label>
<input type="number" name="count" max="" id="count">

<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#item').change(function() {
      var goodsname = $(this).val();
      $.ajax({
        url: "fetch_model2.php",
        method: "POST",
        data: {
          goodsname: goodsname
        },
        success: function(data) {
          $('#count').html(data);
        }
      });
    });
  });
</script>


//fetch_model2.php
<?php
    require ("dbcon.php");
    $output = '';
    $sql = "SELECT DISTINCT count FROM first_table_1 WHERE goodsname = '".$_POST["goodsname"]."' ";;
    $res = mysqli_query($conn , $sql);
    $output .= '<input type="number" max=""></input>';
    if(mysqli_num_rows($res)>0){
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($res)) {

            $output .= '<input type="number" max="'.$row["count"].'"></input>';
        }
    }
    echo $output;
    ?>
```

Comment: а как ты в input делаешь .html(data)?

Comment: и вообще, sql выбирает много товаров, а вам достаточно одного значения, например SELECT MAX(count), а затем success:function(data){$('#count').val(data);} без всяких циклов while

Comment: Так что мне нужно изменить в коде?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Потому что вы вставляете input который присылает ajax внутрь input'a, который у вас изначально прописан.

`$('#count').html(data);`

data не заменяет #count, а вставляется внутрь него

```
<label for="item">Goods</label>
<select name="item" id="item">
  <option value="">Select goods</option>
</select>
<br><br>
<label for="count">Count</label>
<div id="countdiv">
<input type="number" name="count" max="" id="count">
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
$('#item').change(function() {
  var goodsname = $(this).val();
  $.ajax({
    url: "fetch_model2.php",
    method: "POST",
    data: {
      goodsname: goodsname
    },
    success: function(data) {
      $('#countdiv').html(data);
    }
  });
});
  });
</script>
```

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/s2Lby85e/ смотри инспектор и учи матчасть как браузеры работают

Comment: Так что мне нужно изменить в коде?

Comment: в ответе добавил код